# Angular: Injecting service into non-standalone component causes app to break

Tags: angular

I've created my first Angular app and I'm running into trouble importing a service. The app was created in **non-standalone** mode. I generated the component, and the service, using the CLI. When I import the service into my component, every part of the page after the `app-news` instance disappears. No errors are displayed, just…nothing. Note that when I'm typing within the News component, I get autocompletion for the ApiService as expected, but the second I save the file the remainder of the template vanishes. If I comment out the injection in the news component everything returns.

Here are the files I think are relevant. If I'm missing something, let me know and I'll add them.

```
Angular CLI: 17.1.2
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MailinglistComponent } from './mailinglist/mailinglist.component';
import { NewsComponent } from './news/news.component';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    MailinglistComponent,
    NewsComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    ApiService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**main.ts**

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { AppModule } from './app/app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

**mailing-list.html** (this is my "main" page)

```
<div class="main">
    <app-mailinglist></app-mailinglist>
</div>
```

**mailinglist.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-mailinglist',
  templateUrl: './mailinglist.component.html',
  styleUrl: './mailinglist.component.scss'
})
export class MailinglistComponent { }
```

**mailinglist.component.html**

```
<h3>Greetings</h3>

<h3>Board Game News</h3>
<app-news></app-news>

<h3>Upcoming Board Game Conventions</h3>

<h3>Recent Crowdfunding Campaigns</h3>
```

**news.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from '../api.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-news',
  templateUrl: './news.component.html',
  styleUrl: './news.component.scss'
})
export class NewsComponent {
  constructor(
    private api: ApiService
  ) {}
}
```

**api.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Post } from './post';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) { }

  getNews(): Post[] {
    return [];
  }
}
```

Comment: Not sure why the dependency injection could be causing this issue in your project but I have something to highlight about your code. The service `ApiService` is already available in the entire project since it is using `root`, so there is no need to re-defined the `providers` array with the service, just delete it, no need for it. Do that and see if that solves the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example. Below are the points noticed.

1. When using `providedIn: root` for a service, we need not add the service to any of the providers array!
2. Since we are using `httpClient` we need to import the `HttpClientModule` in the `app.module.ts`
3. When I created the `app.mailing.list` component, the selector was renamed by me to `app-mailing-list` instead of `app-mailinglist` (this may just be for me, kindly check the selector for `app-mailinglist` component!

Please compare your code with this working example to see the differences, if the issue still persists please share back the stackblitz with the issue replicated for debugging.

module

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NewsComponent } from './news/news.component';
import { MailingListComponent } from './mailing-list/mailing-list.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, NewsComponent, MailingListComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, AppRoutingModule, HttpClientModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

mailing list html

```
<h3>Greetings</h3>

<h3>Board Game News</h3>
<app-news></app-news>

<h3>Upcoming Board Game Conventions</h3>

<h3>Recent Crowdfunding Campaigns</h3>
```

app component html

```
<div class="main">
  <app-mailing-list></app-mailing-list>
</div>
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jqzmvs?description=Starter%20project%20for%20Node.js,%20a%20JavaScript%20runtime%20built%20on%20Chrome%27s%20V8%20JavaScript%20engine&file=test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapi-test.service.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fnews%2Fnews.component.html,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fnews%2Fnews.component.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fmailing-list%2Fmailing-list.component.html,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts,test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fmailing-list%2Fmailing-list.component.ts&title=node.new%20Starter) -> `cd test` -> `npm i` -> `npm run start`

Comment: Naren, it looks like this did the trick. Once I imported HttpClientModule into app.module.ts it started working. I looked at dozens of SO and blog posts and none of them called that out. Thank you!

Comment: One question. When I first built the app, I used the default, standalone mode. But I converted it to non-standalone because that's what I'm using at my job. But even then I was having trouble getting the import to work. Is the issue that I would have had to import HttpClientModule into the NewsComponent? Because there would be no app.module.ts at that point.

Comment: @commadelimited The newsComponent will be imported in a module in that module we need `HttpClientModule` even better is we can add it to the imports array and exports array of shared module, so that all modules have the import! if you are using standalone the approach is different!